# How can I show that Second Quantization Hamiltonian is Hermitian?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, hamiltonian, second-quantization

How can I show that the non relativistic second quantization hamiltonian 
\begin{equation}
\hat{H}=\lmoustache d^3x \hat{\psi}^\dagger_\alpha(x) T(x)\hat{\psi}^\dagger(x)+\frac{1}{2}\lmoustache d^3x\lmoustache d^3x' \hat{\psi}^\dagger_\alpha(x) \hat{\psi}_\beta(x')V(x,x')\hat{\psi}_\beta(x')\hat{\psi}^\dagger_\alpha(x)\bigr)
\end{equation}
is hermitian?

And how can I show, for both bosons and fermions, that: 
\begin{equation}
[\hat{N},\hat{H}]=0,\\
[\hat{P},\hat{H}]=0
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
\hat{N}=\lmoustache d^3x \hat{\psi}^\dagger_\alpha(x) \hat{\psi}^\dagger(x)_\alpha\\
\hat{P}=\lmoustache d^3x \hat{\psi}^\dagger_\alpha(x) p(x)\hat{\psi}^\dagger(x)_\alpha
\end{equation}
are respectively the total number and momentum operetor.

The following commutation relations are given: 
for bosons:

\begin{equation}
[\hat{\psi}_\alpha(x),\hat{\psi}^\dagger_\beta(x')]=\delta(x-x')\delta_{\alpha\beta}
\end{equation}
for fermions:

\begin{equation}
\{\hat{\psi}_\alpha(x),\hat{\psi}^\dagger_\beta(x')\}=\delta(x-x')\delta_{\alpha\beta}
\end{equation}
I would really appreciate your help,please let me know.

Comment: What commutation relations are you given?